# LINQ TO SQL Repository Pattern Group and Count

Tags: sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a linq to sql query and I am pulling data from it fine but unsure how to add a group or count.

**Linq Code**

```
public IEnumerable<COMPLAINT> GetAllCount()
    {
        try
        {
            return from m in _context.Comp
                   join p in _context.Checklists on m.ID equals p.C_ID
                   orderby m.Received_DT descending
                   select m;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError("Could not get complaint", ex);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

**results**

```
[
 {
"comP_ID": 909,
"received_DT": "2018-01-22T00:00:00",
"Outcome": "Unsatisfactory",
"RecFinding": "Decline"
},
 {
"comP_ID": 909,
"received_DT": "2018-01-22T00:00:00",
"Outcome": "Unsatisfactory",
 "RecFinding": "Sustained"
},
 {
"comP_ID": 909,
"received_DT": "2018-01-22T00:00:00",
"Outcome": "satisfactory",
 "RecFinding": "Decline"
},
 {
"comP_ID": 909,
"received_DT": "2018-01-22T00:00:00",
"Outcome": "satisfactory",
"RecFinding": "Sustained"
},
]
```

**Question**

I am fairly new to the LINQ To SQL and also writing Fluent API's to return the data but I am unsure how do I get the return of only one variable grouped by results or and count to look like this:

```
[
 {
"Decline": 2,
"Sustained": 2,
},
]
```

Or

```
[
 {
"Unsatisfactory": 2,
"satisfactory": 2,
},
]
```

I have tried a few group into g then select new methods, but I am really confused on how to incorporate it into the linq code. Thank you.

Comment: Why do you need the check lists to get the desired results? Also, what do you mean by `//data`?

Comment: I actually don't. I included it in the results for future querying. I will delete it for this question. Thank you. @GertArnold

Comment: Well, still very much is unclear. How would you return the sample results as `IEnumerable<COMPLAINT>`? Why do you mention "repository pattern" in the title? Why are you still joining `Checklists`? And why don't you show what you tried, that usually clarifies more than you might think.